# what would the value of determinant of a matrix be if a specific entry changed?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> What will the value of determinant of matrix $A=\pmatrix{1&3&4\\5&2&a\\6&-2&3}$ be change if we change $a$ to $a+2$.

This is an easy problem because $|A|=-127+20a$ and if we did that changing, we would get $-87+20a$. My question here is:

Can we do this request by doing another way? Where does that $+40$ come from regarding the whole entries of the matrix? Thanks

Comment: **Hint:** Expand by cofactor.

Comment: @Yuta: Make me an illustrating answer. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The determinant, is after all a *multilinear* map on the column / row vectors.

Therefore,
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&4 \\ 5&2&(a+2) \\6&-2&3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&4 \\ 5&2&a \\6&-2&3
\end{pmatrix}
+\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&0 \\ 5&2&2 \\6&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

- The determinant of the second matrix is?
- If I changed $2$ to $3$ or $4$ or $b$, the answer would be?

Comment: I did not notice this version.

Comment: So we should put that $0$s  instead of$3$ and $4$? Am I right?

Comment: Alternatively, $
\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&4 \\ 5&2&(a+2) \\6&-2&3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&0 \\ 5&2&a \\6&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}
+\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&4 \\ 5&2&2 \\6&-2&3
\end{pmatrix}
$, then you can expand for the last column

Comment: Yes, both of you are right.

Comment: What about $$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&4 \\ 5&2&(a+2) \\6&-2&3
\end{pmatrix}
\stackrel{?}{=}
\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&4 \\ 5&2&a \\6&-2&3
\end{pmatrix}
+\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&4 \\ 0&0&2 \\6&-2&3
\end{pmatrix}
$$ ? Is that also equivalent?

Comment: Yes this is also correct

Answer (score 5):

Expand the $|A|$ along column 3.

\begin{align}
|A|&=
\begin{vmatrix}
1&3&4\\
5&2&a\\
6&-2&3
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=
4
\begin{vmatrix}
5&2\\
6&-2
\end{vmatrix}-a
\begin{vmatrix}
1&3\\
6&-2
\end{vmatrix}+3
\begin{vmatrix}
1&3\\
5&2
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=4(-22)-a(-20)+3(-13) \\
&=-127+20a
\end{align}

Comment: The final step would be to substitute $a$ with $a+2$, of course. We could potentially make the logic more clear if we instead computed the determinant using some third variable, such as $x$.

Answer (score 4):

The property of the matrix (in general, for any size $n\times n$):
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a+b&c+d \\ e&f
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
a&c \\ e&f
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
b&d \\ e&f
\end{vmatrix};\\
\begin{vmatrix}
a+b&c \\ d+e&f
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
a&c \\ d&f
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
b&c \\ e&f
\end{vmatrix};$$
Hence:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&3&4 \\ 5&2&(a+2) \\6&-2&3
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
1&3&c+(4-c) \\ 5&2&a+2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \\6&-2&d+(3-d)
\end{vmatrix}=\\
\begin{vmatrix}
1&3&c \\ 5&2&a \\6&-2&d
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
1&3&4-c \\ 5&2&2 \\6&-2&3-d
\end{vmatrix}
$$
For easy calculation of determinant you can create as many zeros as possible (especially in rows/columns).

Comment: Thanks for the extended version!+

Comment: You are welcome! Thanks for the good question! Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

+40 comes from the cofactor of the element A(2,3). It is calculated as:
$$C_{2,3} = (-1)^{2+3} \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3\\
6 & -2
\end{vmatrix} = 20$$
When multiplied with $2$, it becomes 40.